# Cygwin Development Package

Tags: gcc, g++, cygwin

I have installed Cygwin in windows 7. The bin folder does not contain development tools like gcc and g++. I would like to get directions on how I can fixed this problem. I can't compile a simple C/C++ code since the tools are not available. I have the include folder with all the header files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cygwin has ~ 3700 main packages ( 7700 with subpackages).
By default only `Base` category (less than 100 packages) is installed ; for anything else you need to specifically install them.
If you want to install the gcc compiler, you need to select it. You can find it under the `Devel` category, and/or under the gcc search filter.

[image: Selec Package view]